# How to efficiently join a small table to a large one on python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two tables similar to these:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'x': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

   id  x
0   1  0
1   1  1
2   1  2
3   1  3
4   1  4
5   2  5
6   2  6
7   2  7
8   2  8
9   2  9

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'y': [10,100]}, index=[1,2])

     y
1   10
2  100
```

My goal is to multiply `df['x']` by `df['y']` based on `id`. My current solution works, but it seems to me that there should be a more efficient/elegant way of doing this.

This is my code:

```
df_comb = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_on='id', right_index=True)
x_new = df_comb['x'] * df_comb['y']
df_1['x_new'] = x_new.to_numpy()

   id  x  x_new
0   1  0      0
1   1  1     10
2   1  2     20
3   1  3     30
4   1  4     40
5   2  5    500
6   2  6    600
7   2  7    700
8   2  8    800
9   2  9    900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to recover the multiplication factor from `df_2`, then [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) to the `x` column:

```
df_1['x_new'] = df_1['id'].map(df_2['y']).mul(df_1['x'])
```

output:

```
   id  x  x_new
0   1  0      0
1   1  1     10
2   1  2     20
3   1  3     30
4   1  4     40
5   2  5    500
6   2  6    600
7   2  7    700
8   2  8    800
9   2  9    900
```

Comment: is the `map` function using the index of `df_2` to join `df_1`? If the index where a column could we still use the `map` function without using `set_index` and setting the joining column as index?

Comment: Yes it is using the index, if the key was a column, we would need to use `set_index` to be able to `map`. Otherwise a `merge` could be used but this is a bit less efficient. (Is there an issue with `set_index`?)

Comment: Is there any difference between using df_1.mul(df_2) and df_1 * df_2?

Comment: @SergeKashlik `mul` can enable you to select the axis if needed, to fill with a default value in case of NaN, and this is easier to use in a pipeline, other than that this is the same as `*`